# How can I specify that my python file should be invoked via a different binary than python in a PyCharm Run Profile?

Tags: pycharm

I need to invoke the Python file that I am editing (example_file.py) via `panel serve example_file.py`. How would I create a run profile for this?

Be advised this is running on windows and `panel` is actually `panel.exe` and is located in the `Scripts` folder of my virtual environment at `C:\code\pure-python-web-development\venv\Scripts\panel.exe`.